# RecycleViewerAdapter not showing admob Interstitial ads perfectly

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview, admob

i'm trying to integrate interstitial ads from admob in my android project. but, it's working while backPressed, not working in onClick. and i'm really confused about admob rules in my code. can you please check my code, and fix that error is happening? basically i want to follow admob ads policy and make it work perfectly.

**RecycleViewerAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Anime> mData ;
    RequestOptions option;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Anime> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(mContext.getString(R.string.admob_banner));
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        // Request option for Glide
        option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_items,parent,false);
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view) ;
        viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (interstitialAd != null) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                   //do something
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, WebViewActivity.class);
                view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.clcik));
                i.putExtra("action_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                i.putExtra("puzzle_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                i.putExtra("arcade_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                i.putExtra("adventure_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                i.putExtra("sports_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                i.putExtra("racing_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());
                i.putExtra("zombie_link",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getWebsite_link());

                mContext.startActivity(i);
                CustomIntent.customType(mContext,"fadein-to-fadeout");
            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getWebsite_logo()).apply(option).into(holder.img_thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView img_thumbnail;
        LinearLayout view_container;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            img_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        }
    }
}
```

please write an answer by editing my code, it will be better to understand for me and other beginners. sorry for my bad english.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

don't load Ads in adapter ...

use Interface instead

watch this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://youtu.be/yQ3j8B4l6MA)

Comment: i can't do it... can you please edit my code and post your answer?